# Modifying chrome.storage.sync from popup script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with options.js and popup.js.
I have a setting that I want the user to control both from options and popup *alternatively*.
In options it's straight forward:

**options.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Random options placeholder</title></head>
<body>  
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="activate">
  Active
</label>

<div id="status"></div>
<button id="save">Save</button>

<script src="options.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**options.js**

```
function save_options() {
    var isActive = document.getElementById('activate').checked;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
      isActive: true
    }, function() {
      // Update status to let user know options were saved.
      var status = document.getElementById('status');
      status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
      setTimeout(function() {
        status.textContent = '';
      }, 750);
    });
  }
```

but in popup.js I don't understand how to use the `chrome.storage.sync.set`
to update the same shared value (isActive).

**popup.js** (fail)

```
var isActive = document.getElementById('activate').checked;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
      isActive: true
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The popup - assuming it's a browserAction or pageAction popup - is an entirely different extension page with its own html file and own DOM in its own separate small window for which you can invoke its own separate devtools. Basically your popup.html should be similar to options.html.

Comment: So they can't update shared values?

Comment: Well yeah okay I understand now. thanks again :)

Comment: All pages in the extension share the same storage, just not the variables and DOM.

Comment: So how should I access this shared storage then?

Comment: I don't follow. You're already accessing it. See also [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).